# error: expected end of struct constant

Tags: llvm-ir

I'm trying to generate an array of pointers to structs, but I get this error:

```
llc: llvm_test.ll:7:64: error: expected end of struct constant
```

This is the full code:

```
@gc.info.type1 = global {i32, i32} {i32 1, i32 2}
@gc.info.types = global [1 x i8* ] { {i32, i32}* @gc.info.type1* }
```

The error is on the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How my solution ended up using bitcast (thanks to #llvm IRC channel):

```
@gc.info.type2 = global {i32, i32, i32} {i32 1, i32 2, i32 3}
@gc.info.type2_ptr = global i8* bitcast ({i32, i32, i32}* @gc.info.type2 to i8*)
@gc.info.types = global [2 x i8** ] [ i8** @gc.info.type1_ptr, i8** @gc.info.type2_ptr ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@gc.info.type1 = global {i32, i32} {i32 1, i32 2}
@gc.info.types = global [1 x {i32, i32}* ] [ {i32, i32}* @gc.info.type1 ]
```

Comment: Won't work, because I will have structs of different types in the array. Thanks, though.